# How to test a product after release in Github actions?

Tags: github, testing, github-actions

I want to test my product/package after every release. For example, I have a package `orchestrate-command-status` and I am releasing to npm using github actions. Once the release is done I want to test the package by installing and checking the version and some more commands. Currently I am doing like below:

```
job:
 test:
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   steps:
      - name: Installing package
      - run: npm i orchestrate-command-status
      - run: orchestrator --version
```

Is there any way I can do the validation in github actions like version is the latest version or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would be the return of the `orchestrator --version` command? Depending on the context, you could eventually use this action to check the command line output: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/test-cli-commands-action (this is an action I created to test command lines outputs).

Comment: Thank you for the response. My intention is to test the command line outputs. ```orchestrator --version``` will return the current version like ```x.y.z```

Comment: If you have a way to extract this latest version in your workflow (for example, using `$ORCHESTRATOR_VERSION`), you could use the action I shared above passing the version as `contains` field, or using a command line like: `run: orchestrator --version | grep "$ORCHESTRATOR_VERSION"`